# How do I grab the last value in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can parse out the int by doing

```
parseInt($('#count_of_stations').html())
```

if the value is like this "2stations" that will return 2 but now I need to get the integers out in this format

```
one1
two2
three3
four4
five5
```

How do i get just the number out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number will always be 0-9, you can use [*slice()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/slice) with a negative offset:

```
var num = $('#count_of_stations').text().slice(-1);
```

Alternatively, if the start of the string *upto the number* will always be the same, you can use *slice()* with a positive offset:

```
"mystring1".slice(8); // -> 1
"mystring12".slice(8); // -> 12
```

If those first two suggestions don't meet your requirements, you can use [*match()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/match) with a regular expression:

```
var num = $('#count_of_stations').text().match(/\d+$/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regular expression like \d$